# If / Switch statement for creating class instance or creating an empty variable

Tags: swift, class, if-statement, variables, switch-statement

I believe this is something simple to do but I don't have knowledge of it, I'm still a noobie (I'm searching for days, still didn't able to find an answer or similar problem, finally I decided to ask)

Thing is I have classes named (basically databases) : QuestionBank001, QuestionBank002 .. etc

So when I pick a questionbank and go to another viewcontroller, I want to able to create a specific instance.
But I have to create this variable just under UIViewController, because there are functions requires it :

```
class test1: UIViewController {

    var questions = QuestionBank001()
```

So my problem is, I don't know how to add an if / switch statement (or a get/set?) correctly. Or how to initiate it.
If I able to create an empty variable (without type) I would use viewDidLoad() section and make a switch statement there but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **is** in a **switch** block. See "Type Casting for Any and AnyObject" in the Swift Programming Language (though it's not limited to Any of course). They have an extensive example:

```
for thing in things {
    switch thing {
    case 0 as Int:
        println("zero as an Int")
    case 0 as Double:
        println("zero as a Double")
    case let someInt as Int:
        println("an integer value of \(someInt)")
    case let someDouble as Double where someDouble > 0:
        println("a positive double value of \(someDouble)")
// here it comes:
    case is Double:
        println("some other double value that I don't want to print")
    case let someString as String:
        println("a string value of \"\(someString)\"")
    case let (x, y) as (Double, Double):
        println("an (x, y) point at \(x), \(y)")
    case let movie as Movie:
        println("a movie called '\(movie.name)', dir. \(movie.director)")
    default:
        println("something else")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have either a base type or a protocol from which all of the question banks inherit.  If a question bank is something like an array of questions then then you have the simplest case, just set your array to empty:

`var questions = QuestionBank001()`

Otherwise there are a could of solutions:

1. Make the variable lazy and it will load the first question from the db the first time someone tries to use questions:

```
lazy var questions: QuestionBank = {
  //code to load the first question bank here
}()
```

2. Make the variable optional.  You now need to unwrap it everywhere you need it with a guard at the beginning of the function.  If you need to be able to represent and empty or missing question bank then this will help you correctly handle the empty state:

```
var questions: QuestionBank?
```

3. Make the variable initially set to an empty question bank that shows no questions and has no answers:

```
var questions = QuestionBank.makeEmpty()
```